# How to download multiple files using Python 3.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, http

A beginner's question - I have a .txt file containing a list of .html files I want to download. The content of the file looks like this:

```
http://www.example.com/file1.html
http://www.example.com/file2.html
http://www.example.com/file3.html
```

I can get Python to download a single file using the code below, but I want it to read each URL from the .txt file and download each .html file.

```
import urllib.request
url = 'http://www.example.com/file1.html'
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, '/users/user/Downloads/file1.html')
```

Is there a simple way of doing this?

Comment: what have you tried?  maybe read some tutorials on how to use `for` loops

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
   for line in f:
      url = line
      path = 'your path'+url.split('/', -1)[-1]
      urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, path.rstrip('\n'))
```

Comment: you could use `enumerate()` instead of `i=0` and `i+=1`

Comment: you could try to get filename from `http://www.example.com/file1.html` and create `'/users/user/Downloads/file1.html'`

Comment: yes indeed, your solution is way more optimal, thanks :D

Comment: Thanks. As above, I get an error message where Python is reading the line breaks in the .txt file as if they were part of the URL: OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: '/users/user/Downloads/file1.html\n'. Any ideas for how to overcome this?

Comment: '\n' means it adds new line to the path. A simple path.rstrip() will do the trick

Comment: That works. I've proposed an edit to your code showing where I inserted path.rstrip

Answer (score 2):

First you have to read your .txt file as something you can iterate over. Then you can use a `for` loop to go one-by-one over the url links:

```
import os

urls = open('pages.txt', 'r')
for i, url in enumerate(urls):
    path = '/users/user/Downloads/{}'.format(os.path.basename(url)
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, path)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly the kind of approach I had in mind. I've added the missing bracket at the end of the penultimate line, but I still get an error message where Python is reading the line breaks in the .txt file as if they were part of the URL: OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: '/users/user/Downloads/file1.html\n'. Any ideas for how to overcome this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a ThreadPool or ProcessingPool for concurrency, like [this tutorial](http://%20https://www.quickprogrammingtips.com/python/how-to-download-multiple-files-concurrently-in-python.html)

```
import requests
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool

def download_url(url):
  print("downloading: ",url)
  # assumes that the last segment after the / represents the file name
  # if url is abc/xyz/file.txt, the file name will be file.txt
  file_name_start_pos = url.rfind("/") + 1
  file_name = url[file_name_start_pos:]

  r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
  if r.status_code == requests.codes.ok:
    with open(file_name, 'wb') as f:
      for data in r:
        f.write(data)
  return url


urls = ["https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts",
        "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments",
        "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos",
        "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos",
        "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums"
        ]

# Run 5 multiple threads. Each call will take the next element in urls list
results = ThreadPool(5).imap_unordered(download_url, urls)
for r in results:
    print(r)
```